# First Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page one my website that I'd like to emulate into a 'newtab' chrome extension.

I want to make something similar to this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animatedtabs-a-new-gif-on/kenhfdoiondldpcoajdbackbnmehgahl?hl=en

I have a lot of information on my server that i'd like to be able to serve as a chrome newtab extension - and this extension above loads a different GIF everytime a new tab is opened - how do they get data from their server? I don't seem to be able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, for anyone wondering.  The answer came in the form of this page:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Which basically states that if you put a URL into the 'permissions' field in the `manifest.json` file, you can then access that URL in your application using the JS found on that page, eg:

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.json", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // innerText does not let the attacker inject HTML elements.
    document.getElementById("resp").innerText = xhr.responseText;
  }
}
xhr.send();`

I've now got my chrome extension working perfectly!

Comment: This is not particular to chrome extensions, any browser/webpage has this (ajax)